# Should we split an interface if only some methods of the interface are needed

Tags: c#, oop

Imagine we have an interface like below:

```
public interface ISome
{
    void MethodOne();
    int MethodTwo();
    string MethodThree();
}
```

A class implements the interface:

```
public class Some : ISome
{
    // Implementation...
}
```

Here is how it may be used:

```
public class App
{
    public App(ISome)
    {
        // This class needs the whole interface: All three methods
    }
}
```

I have a new requirement and it only needs one method from it: `MethodThree` and it can use the implementation provided by `Some`. Now I have 2 options:

1. Use `ISome` in the new class, like `App` uses it. The problem with this is that the new class does not really depend on the whole interface but only one method.
2. Split the interface like this using inheritance:

   ```
   public interface INewSome
   {
       string MethodThree();
   }

   public interface ISome : INewSome
   {
       void MethodOne();
       int MethodTwo();
   }
   ```

The benefits of the 2nd option are:

1. The new class will depend on `INewSome`
2. `Some` still implements the whole interface so existing code will not break.
3. Unit testing will be much clearer since we know we just need to mock/stub one method in `INewSome`

**Questions**

1. I cannot think of a benefit for option 1 aside from not having to introduce a new interface. Do you know of a benefit with option 1?
2. Do you have another suggestion?
3. Am I overlooking anything and is this good/bad design?

Comment: Time to learn about the `I` in [SOLID](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/the-interface-segregation-principle-with-c-examples/)

Comment: @maccettura thanks but I know about I in SOLID. Can you elaborate what you are trying to say? The question is not about a different implementation, I hope that is clear from the question.

Comment: If you know about SOLID, specifically `I` (interface segregation). Then why are you asking SO?  You already know the answer...

Comment: "would you go with..."  **immediately** triggers this question as off topic for me, since that makes it clear you are looking for opinions, not facts.

Comment: @Claies I removed that. Maybe I need to move this question to code review instead.

Comment: I have edited the question so it is not opinion based. And other suggestions to make the question better so it is not on hold?

Comment: removing that one line doesn't make it not an opinionated question;  The entire question involves asking for other people to interpret design principles.  It doesn't involve any "broken" code that needs to be fixed, which is a key of Stack Overflow specifically.

Comment: Plus it's not really clear what you might expect responses to be;  In particular, you dismissed an answer which seems perfectly reasonable with "I am not asking for another implementation", but no implementation was provided in the answer.

Comment: that is a good question why did it put on hold...

Comment: I go for option 1 because:
1. you can implement as much interfaces as you need (opposed to
 to classes).
2. Microsoft also does that, not every method implemented from an interface is in use. 
3. the code is more minimal and clear.
4. Some methods are sometimes sufficient to characterize objects (`public class MyGenericClass<T> where T : ISome`)

Answer (score 2):

what you have done in the option 2 is correct and goes perfectly with the fourth goal which is Interface Segregation Principle 
 From Wikipedia *`many client-specific interfaces are better than one general-purpose interface`*

Comment: Sorry but that is not the question: I am not asking for another implementation.

Comment: @CodingYoshi could you be a little clear